# Copyright infringment: using dictionary definitions

Tags: copyright

I am planning to build an online web app and a mobile app for learning vocabulary.

Functions:
- User can create lists (eg. personalities, phrasal verbs etc.) and add words to the list with definitions.
- These list can be made public.

If users were to copy dictionary definitions, for instance Oxford or Cambridge) and make the word lists public, is it a copyright infringement? Am I responsible for this activity? Can dictionary owners charge me against copyright issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If users were to copy dictionary definitions, for instance Oxford or Cambridge) and make the word lists public, is it a copyright infringement?

If the dictionary entries are protected by copyright then your user has infringed that copyright by posting the dictionary entries.

> Am I responsible for this activity?

No. But you may be responsible for removing it if you get a request.

> Can dictionary owners charge me against copyright issue?

If you follow the procedures outlines in the DMCA you can be protected from liability.

Answer (score 1):

As described, that is copyright infringement. A specific word is not protected by copyright nor is the idea of its definition, but the actual expression of that definition is protected. However, protection is not permanent, and some versions of Webster's are in the public domain. In principle, one could find such a dictionary out there.

Comment: YouTube, for example, let users to upload content. Thus, there are lot of misuses of the copyrighted material. Nonetheless YouTube is not banned. 
Considering this way, a flashcard app cannot be charged against copyright infringement, can it?

Comment: YouTube goes to great lengths in its ToS **and** its compliance with take down laws to make sure it cannot be sued. Do you?

Comment: @kk-dev11 There are laws, especially the DMCA, that protect them, and provide these companies with procedures on how to deal with that kind of content. And trust me, people do get banned on YouTube.